# GifImageView: как и где указать источник анимации

Tags: android, gif

В общем, проблема с подключением библиотеки [GifImageView](https://github.com/felipecsl/GifImageView),
мне нужно поместить анимацию gif. 
Создаю элемент

```
<com.felipecsl.gifimageview.library.GifImageView
    android:id="@+id/gifImageView"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:scaleType="fitCenter"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
```

но как и где указать мою gif анимацию? В примере там только загрузка из сети.
может кто знает? Или может есть лучше библиотека?

Answer (score 1):

Как через разметку не знаю, но программно так:

```
gifView.setBytes(bitmapData);
```

Получение `Bitmap`:

```
InputStream is = context.getResources().openRawResource(R.drawable.my_image);
bitmapData = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(is);
```

Comment: А как получить bitmapdata с анимации из ресурсов?

Comment: @user186301 обновил ответ

Comment: Пишет что bitmap не подходит. Может нужно типа  bytes

Comment: @user186301 я с этой библиотекой не работал. Попробуйте.

Answer (score 1):

В [ByteArrayHttpClient](https://github.com/felipecsl/GifImageView/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/felipecsl/gifimageview/app/ByteArrayHttpClient.java) там просто читается файл в `byte[]`, дальше этот массив отдается в `gifImageView.setBytes(byte[] bytes)`.

Наверное, будет что-то похожее на

```
@Override protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    gifImageView = (GifImageView) findViewById(R.id.gifImageView);

    InputStream ins = getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.gif_file);
    gifImageView.setBytes(org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils.toByteArray(in));
    gifImageView.startAnimation();
}
```

Файл должен быть в `/res/raw/`.